# Why my python for loops and list.remove() is not behaving properly or i am lacking some information?

Tags: python, list

i am using this code and i want to remove all the 2's from the array arr .
but when i am running it is returning me [2,2,2,"string"]

```
 arr = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,"string"]

 for i in arr:
   if i == 2:
     arr.remove(i)

 print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb is: Don't try to mutate the list you are iterating. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it) question :)

If you want to modify the list while iterating it. You may try this:

```py
arr = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,"string"]

for i in arr[:]:
    if i == 2:
        arr.remove(i)
```

With *list comprehension*, we can make this better and more pythonic:

```
arr = [element for element in arr if element != 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

try like this:

```
arr = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, "string"]

arr2 = [n for n in arr if n is not 2]

print(arr2)
```